# Is it possible to make span behaviours like table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I was wondering is it possible to have 2 span behaviours like table cell in div. so when the 2nd span word wrap, it does not go back to the 1st span's position,
it is hard to say , so if you check the code below, it will easy to understand, 
I want the first piece of code modified to show like 2nd
1st piece : the code to be fix

```
<div style="display:block;width:100px;">
<span>test</span>
<span>test testasdf asdfasdf asdf asdfa sdfa sdfa sdf asdf asd fasd fasd</span>
</div>
```

2nd piece, the expected layout

```
<div style="display:block;width:100px;">
<table>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">test</td>
<td>test testasdf asdfasdf asdf asdfa sdfa sdfa sdf asdf asd fasd fasd</td>
</div>
```

Comment: Ideally if you want to make one element behave like another, use the original one. If you absolutely need to do it, there is css `display:table` **Side Note**: your table html is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. `display` property can be set as both `table` or `table-cell`. Both property values will behave as you would expect. `table` will behave like a table and `table-cell` behaves like a `td`. There's plenty of other properties for `display` as well. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

```css
div {
  display: table;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the layout you want by changing the `display` property of the containing div. `table`, `flex` and `grid` will work.

Using `table` and `flex` may require some additional styling to the `span`.

NOTE: If a table is what you need, and you are able to change the HTML then do that instead.

**Examples**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.table span {
  display: table-cell;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex span:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <span>test</span>
  <span>test testasdf asdfasdf asdf asdfa sdfa sdfa sdf asdf asd fasd fasd</span>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <span>test</span>
  <span>test testasdf asdfasdf asdf asdfa sdfa sdfa sdf asdf asd fasd fasd</span>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <span>test</span>
  <span>test testasdf asdfasdf asdf asdfa sdfa sdfa sdf asdf asd fasd fasd</span>
</div>
```